# Exception on android side

Tags: android, exception, crashlytics

I'm using crashlytycs and recently i begin to get such exception, but i don't know how to reproduce it on my application.

I know how to fix it. The fix is to use runOnUiThread, but i don't know the point where this exception happens.

When i got exception, i see the line of it in logs, but this one is different, because exception occurs in android class, not mine. Can you give me some advices about where can i search for this exception. I'm not changing ui in asyncTask background. I use volley for networking.

Error Log:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7406)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4595)
       at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11301)
       at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:11250)
       at android.widget.TextView.updateAfterEdit(TextView.java:7817)
       at android.widget.Editor.finishBatchEdit(Editor.java:1330)
       at android.widget.Editor.endBatchEdit(Editor.java:1313)
       at android.widget.TextView.endBatchEdit(TextView.java:6084)
       at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.endBatchEdit(EditableInputConnection.java:82)
       at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.finishComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:292)
       at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.finishComposingText(EditableInputConnection.java:199)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocusNoStartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1448)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onWindowFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1500)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:4211)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace please

Comment: i updated, the full exception is in the topic

Comment: You said you are not touching the ui from any AsyncTask, but maybe you have a TextWatcher?

Comment: i do have a TextWatcher in 11 places in code. what are you suggesting, sir?

Comment: It looks like the crash is originated by a TextView.updateAfterEdit() method

Comment: Maybe you change text in somewhere,.Plz provide your asyncTask .

Comment: @tinysunlight i don't have async task, i'm using volley. And in documentations it states that onResponse and onError work on uiThread, so i think it's not the problem. I have some magic with textWatcher and interfaces, maybe it's the problem

Comment: Maybe it should `runOnUIThread`?

Comment: No. Volley'onResponse  works on thread create Request works on. if your create request on workthread,add runOnUiThread.

Comment: @tinysunlight it's not my code, i wouldn't use volley, but i checked - volley request is created and called from uithread, so i think it's not a problem. Anyway it would crash everytime in case it wasn't the uithread

Comment: You are not sure volley request is created on UiThread . Try to log threadid in onResponse.

Comment: @tinysunlight
onResponse:
11-11 15:42:25.194 31554-31554/com.somepackage.mock D/Thread!: On UI thread

onError:
11-11 15:44:35.274 31554-31554/com.somepackage.mock D/Thread!: On UI thread

Comment: if only i knew how to reproduce this exception

Comment: Where do you change text of TextView? Plz tell me how to use your app

Comment: @tinysunlight thanks for support, but i can't show you the code, because it's not ,mine. I can only describe what happens there. When user types two or more symbols it sends request to server and then sets the adapter of autocompleteTextView with strings that came from server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94828/discussion-between-tiny-sunlight-and-jenya-kyrmyza).

Comment: Can you show code  where you create volley request and  where you update adapter